# How to get country name from country code in Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I get the country code from `field_data_commerce_customer_address` table in drupal commerce. Now how to get the full country name from this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use drupal cores country manager like this :

```
$country_list = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('country_manager')->getList();
$country_name = $country_list[$country_code]->render();
```